# Why is this regexp invalid?

Tags: regex, eclipse

```
(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{9}$)
```

Why is this regular expression valid using ruby online validator, but the same expression seems to be invalid in Eclipse?

Comment: what does "seems to be invalid" mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse probably only recognizes `^` as the start of the input and `$` as the end of the input, instead of the start- and end of a line. Try enabling multi-line mode:

```
(?m)(?:(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{9}$))
```

More info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score 0):

Use double backslashes:

```
(^\\d{5}$)|(^\\d{9}$)
```

That is because in Java and C++ and most other languages, a backslash is the escape character in a string. To get a literal backslash, you must type two backslashes.

To explain this further, I will make a table:

```
\t  |  tab character
\n  |  newline character
\d  |  ?????
\\d |  literal backslash, then "d"
```

In Ruby (and JavaScript and some other languages), a regex is set off with a special delimiter, like this:

```
myRegex = /\d+/
```

This special "literal regular expression notation" lets the program know that you are creating a regular expression, so it allows you to use `\d` without escaping it.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work with either slashes.

Comment: @user2508615 What programming language are you using? What does "doesn't work" mean? Where is your current code? What are you trying to do? It's kind of hard to help when I don't really even know what the problem is.

Comment: I'm trying to validate xml file against the xsd, where one of the field is presented with that regular expression.

Comment: @user2508615 And where is your code?